# Mathematics Educators Stackexchange and its relationship to statistics

Tags: discussion

Stackexchange recently opened up a new site, [matheducators.stackexchange.com](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com), for public beta.

It is a site for math teachers to discuss how to be better teachers.

There have already been a few statistics education questions. Because mathematics and statistics are often taught by the same instructors and with similar methods, I'm sure a lot more questions will arise about teaching statistics.

One thing I'm not sure about is how many stats teachers are currently on the site. If there is anyone on CV interested in statistics education, we would welcome you with open arms.

Comment: @AndreSilva This site is not for teaching math to newbies, it's about how to be a teacher. So the questions are about how to design a course, how to write exams, etc.

Comment: *There have already been a few statistics education questions* - only two with the 'statistics' tag (i.e. less than 1%) so far.

Comment: @Glen_b: Literally, less than 1% are only a few indeed.